# Is it possible to deploy JSF-Web-Apps in WSO2 AS 5.2?

Tags: jsf, wso2

I tried the following steps:

At first I installed the feature "WSO2 Carbon - J2EE Runtime Environment" in the AS. Then I created a new dynamic web project in Eclipse with Servlet Module 2.5 and a configuration for JSF 1.2 using Myfaces 1.2.9 and a JSF-HTML-Template. After I had written "hello" in the view, I tested it with "run on server" in Eclipse and it runs. Then I created a WAR-File and deployed it in the AS with pasting the file in "asroot/repository/deployment/server/webapps".

Then I tried the page and it throws this error:

"/NewFile.jsp(2,57) PWC6188: The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jsf/core cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application

Caused by:
org.apache.jasper.JasperException - /NewFile.jsp(2,57) PWC6188: The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jsf/core cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application"

I tried it also on a local Tomcat-Server with the same result like in Eclipse.

The libs in the WAR are:

javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-1.2.1.jar
javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-api-1.2.1.jar
commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar
commons-codec-1.3.jar
commons-collections-3.2.jar
commons-digester-1.8.jar
commons-discovery-0.4.jar
commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
myfaces-api-1.2.9.jar
myfaces-impl-1.2.9.jar

Answer (score 0):

This could be a classloading issue. Please put webapp-classloading.xml file in META-INF directory of your web application with following configurations

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

   <Classloading xmlns="http://wso2.org/projects/as/classloading">
         <Environments>Tomcat</Environments>
   </Classloading>
```

Refer http://docs.wso2.org/display/AS520/Webapp+ClassLoading